# Is there special variable represent array itself in a each block for Enumerable?

Tags: ruby

I have a code like this:

```
array = [100, 90, 120, 100, 110]
array.each_with_index.map do |v, i|
    next if i == array.size - 1
    array[i+1] - v
end
```

And I thought it would be nicer if I can write like this:

```
array = [100, 90, 120, 100, 110]
array.each_with_index.map do |v, i|
    next if i == _.size - 1
    _[i+1] - v
end
```

So I want to know if there is a special variable that represent array itself in a Enumerator block.

Does anyone know about that?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are looking to copy one array to another conditionally then select may help you out http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has block scope, meaning, any new variable you define inside the `do/end` block will be only in that scope and not be accessible anywhere else. In IRB, [_ has a special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick/864710#864710), which is the value of the last expression executed. That isn't the case when executing a Ruby program, however. What you can do is define a temporary _ variable inside the block itself that will hold a reference to the array:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.each do |x|
  _ = arr
  p _ #=> will print [1,2,3] 3 times
end

p _ #=> undefined local variable
```

Other than that, I'd consider monkey-patching `Array` but that's a risky operation. Most of the times with questions like these, however, if you give a better context of what you're trying to achieve, there's a simpler solution than hacks like these.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is using [`each_cons`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Enumerable/each_cons), which iterates the given block for each array of consecutive elements:

```
 array.each_cons(2).map { |a, b| a - b }
 # => [10, -30, 20, -10]
```